# Emacs Monky Error - Removing old name: no such file or directory

Tags: unix, plugins, emacs

I'm trying to use Monky for working with Mercurial. However, I don't think this error is isolated to Monky since the only google results I found for this error were caused by seemingly unrelated reasons.

When I try using the plugin I get the error "Removing old name: No such file or directory, /var/folders/1h/" followed by some seemingly random characters and temporary directories ending with the file "monky-temp-file" with some more random characters appended at the end.

I've tried commenting out everything else from my .emacs, making sure my .emacs and .emacs.d aren't symbolic links, increasing plugin permissions, removing my .hgrc, and re-downloading the plugin.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To follow this question up, I have the exact same problem. This error only appears on the mac os x version of vanilla emacs (Emacs.app). Interestingly enough, for *both* emacs 23 and 24.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently using emacs 23 on OS X

Answer (score 2):

As a stopgap, you can use Aquamacs (either 2.4 or the 3.0 nightly builds based on emacs 24). Also, invoking emacs from the terminal works as well. Since both Aquamacs and terminal emacs work, I am a little baffled as to what is different.

Update: installing with macport fixed the error

`sudo port install emacs-app`

Comment: Building from source as you originally suggested didn't work. I also tried an install from macports but that's failing on the ncurses dependency. When I try to install ncurses with macports I get further cryptic errors.

I also noticed that I get the same error with Aquamacs, unlike you. However it does work in terminal emacs. Weird stuff. Thanks for the suggestion on trying terminal emacs, I guess that will have to do for now.

Comment: Darn, that's no fun. Perhaps it's something in the bundled lisp files? Just a shot in the dark, but perhaps try using something like AppCleaner to remove old versions of Emacs.app (along with preference files) and then try Aquamacs.app? This is completely guesswork, though.

Answer (score 1):

I tracked down the cause of this bug to a misunderstanding between Emacs and Mercurial about text encoding. The Mercurial command server says it wants UTF8, which Monky convert to utf8, but Emacs wants utf-8 (with a hyphen).

My quick fix is to put the following into my .emacs:

(defun monky-cmdserver-get-encoding (&optional default)
  "Get encoding stored in `monky-cmd-hello-message'."
  default)

This ignores Mercurial's return value, assuming that it's utf8.

Comment: Wow, sorry, I totally missed this response. My workflow has since changed so I'm not using monky anymore. I really appreciate the response, though, and hopefully this will help anyone running into a similar issue.